# Chrome border color issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m

Chrome is doing something odd with border colors in TBODY sections.  There are lots of questions and answers about issues with the CSS: "border: 1px solid black;" or other colors.  What i am seeing with TBODY TD elements is that when the TABLE element has "border-collapse: collapse;" then no color is displayed.  If you set that to "separate" then the border colors are visible with the expected default cell spacing.

The following CSS is copied from the app's stylesheet.  The table in question has the class "List" applied

```
    .List {
       margin: 0 auto;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       padding: 0;
       width: 90%;
   }
   .List TH, TD {
       border: 1px solid #000;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       vertical-align: top;
   }
```

Displays fine in FireFox.  Is this a known Chrome bug?

Comment: What exactly doesnt display well in Chrome ? Try the webkit parameters for experimentation if you want.

Comment: can you attach a jsfiddle with bug ?

Comment: Working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/MTudN/).