# Chrome border radius and background color

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Similar to [Chrome border color issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525285/chrome-border-color-issue) issue. Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gU52K/

I want table with specific background (white) and rounder border. In chrome, just borders work fine, borders with color - not working.

Firefox/IE output:  1,2 and 4 table are with rounded border, 3 table with cornered border.

Chrome output (latest, Version 32.0.1700.14 beta-m Aura):  1 table is with rounded border, 2 and 4 table without border at all, 3 table with cornered border.

FF output is the expected behavior, where is the problem?

HTML:

```
<table class="List">
    <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="List BG">
    <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="List BG Col">
    <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="List BG Sep">
    <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.List {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.List.BG {
    background-color: white;
    /* border-collapse: separate; is default */
}
.List.BG.Col {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.List.BG.Sep {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
.List.BG.Col {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

to

```
.List.BG.Col {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: that is exactly what .List.BG.Sep demonstrates: 'collapse' makes borders cornered in both FF and Chrome, but 'separate' (which i think is default) in FF has round borders (as expected) and in chrome the border disapear. [this is what i see in chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KrvoH.png)